# typeorm FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Tags: typescript, sqlite, orm, typeorm

New to typeorm, receiving FOREIGN KEY constraint failed when trying to insert an object and it's relation into the DB.  Query log at bottom of post.

> Account.ts

```
import UploadInfo from "./UploadInfo";
import {
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  OneToMany,
  Entity,
  JoinColumn,
} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export default class Account {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Column()
  username!: string;

  @Column()
  password!: string;

  ...

  @OneToMany((type) => UploadInfo, (uploadInfo) => uploadInfo.uploader, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn()
  uploads: UploadInfo[];
}
```

> UploadInfo.ts

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  ManyToOne,
  JoinColumn,
} from "typeorm";
import Account from "./Account";

@Entity()
export default class UploadInfo {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;
  @Column()
  url!: string;
  @ManyToOne((type) => Account, (account) => account.uploads)
  @JoinColumn()
  uploader: Account;
}
```

> YoutubeAccount.ts

```
@Entity()
export default class YoutubeAccount extends Account { ... }
```

Calling code:

```
  await AppDataSource.initialize();
  let upload = new UploadInfo();
  upload.url = "youtube.com/derp";
  account.uploads = [upload];
  await AppDataSource.manager.save(account);
```

Query log:

```
query: BEGIN TRANSACTION

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: SELECT null as database, null as schema, * FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "type" = 'table' AND "name" IN ('upload_info')

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: SELECT null as database, null as schema, * FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "type" = 'table' AND "name" IN ('account')

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: SELECT null as database, null as schema, * FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "type" = 'table' AND "name" IN ('youtube_account')

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: SELECT null as database, null as schema, * FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "type" = 'table' AND "name" IN ('upload_preset_duration')  

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: SELECT null as database, null as schema, * FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "type" = 'table' AND "name" IN ('upload_preset_input_directory')

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: SELECT null as database, null as schema, * FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "type" = 'table' AND "name" IN ('upload_preset')

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: SELECT null as database, null as schema, * FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "type" = 'table' AND "name" IN ('upload_info')

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: SELECT null as database, null as schema, * FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "type" = 'index' AND "tbl_name" IN ('upload_info')

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: SELECT null as database, null as schema, * FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "type" = 'index' AND "tbl_name" IN ('account')

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: SELECT null as database, null as schema, * FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "type" = 'index' AND "tbl_name" IN ('youtube_account')     

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: SELECT null as database, null as schema, * FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "type" = 'index' AND "tbl_name" IN ('upload_preset_duration')

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: SELECT null as database, null as schema, * FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "type" = 'index' AND "tbl_name" IN ('upload_preset_input_directory')

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: SELECT null as database, null as schema, * FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "type" = 'index' AND "tbl_name" IN ('upload_preset')       

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: SELECT null as database, null as schema, * FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "type" = 'index' AND "tbl_name" IN ('upload_info')

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA table_info("upload_info")

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA index_list("upload_info")

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA foreign_key_list("upload_info")

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA table_info("account")

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA index_list("account")

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA foreign_key_list("account")

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA table_info("youtube_account")

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA index_list("youtube_account")

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA foreign_key_list("youtube_account")

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA table_info("upload_preset_duration")

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA index_list("upload_preset_duration")

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA foreign_key_list("upload_preset_duration")

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA table_info("upload_preset_input_directory")

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA index_list("upload_preset_input_directory")

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA foreign_key_list("upload_preset_input_directory")

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA table_info("upload_preset")

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA index_list("upload_preset")

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA foreign_key_list("upload_preset")

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA table_info("upload_info")

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA index_list("upload_info")

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA foreign_key_list("upload_info")

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: SELECT * FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "type" = 'table' AND "name" = 'typeorm_metadata'

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: CREATE TABLE "temporary_upload_info" ("id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "url" varchar NOT NULL, "uploaderId" integer, CONSTRAINT "FK_687298e6cc5e44492f24dee010a" FOREIGN KEY ("uploaderId") REFERENCES "youtube_account" ("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: INSERT INTO "temporary_upload_info"("id", "url", "uploaderId") SELECT "id", "url", "uploaderId" FROM "upload_info"

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: DROP TABLE "upload_info"

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: ALTER TABLE "temporary_upload_info" RENAME TO "upload_info"

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: CREATE TABLE "temporary_upload_info" ("id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "url" varchar NOT NULL, "uploaderId" integer)

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: INSERT INTO "temporary_upload_info"("id", "url", "uploaderId") SELECT "id", "url", "uploaderId" FROM "upload_info"

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: DROP TABLE "upload_info"

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: ALTER TABLE "temporary_upload_info" RENAME TO "upload_info"

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: CREATE TABLE "temporary_upload_info" ("id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "url" varchar NOT NULL, "uploaderId" integer, CONSTRAINT "FK_687298e6cc5e44492f24dee010a" FOREIGN KEY ("uploaderId") REFERENCES "youtube_account" ("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: INSERT INTO "temporary_upload_info"("id", "url", "uploaderId") SELECT "id", "url", "uploaderId" FROM "upload_info"

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: DROP TABLE "upload_info"

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: ALTER TABLE "temporary_upload_info" RENAME TO "upload_info"

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: CREATE TABLE "temporary_upload_info" ("id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "url" varchar NOT NULL, "uploaderId" integer, CONSTRAINT "FK_687298e6cc5e44492f24dee010a" FOREIGN KEY ("uploaderId") REFERENCES "youtube_account" ("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION, CONSTRAINT "FK_687298e6cc5e44492f24dee010a" FOREIGN KEY ("uploaderId") REFERENCES "account" ("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: INSERT INTO "temporary_upload_info"("id", "url", "uploaderId") SELECT "id", "url", "uploaderId" FROM "upload_info"

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: DROP TABLE "upload_info"

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: ALTER TABLE "temporary_upload_info" RENAME TO "upload_info"

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: COMMIT

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: BEGIN TRANSACTION

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: INSERT INTO "youtube_account"("id", "username", "password", "proxy", "profilePath", "recoveryEmail", "phoneNumber") VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) -- PARAMETERS: ["redacted","redacted","redacted","redacted","redacted","redacted"]

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query: INSERT INTO "upload_info"("id", "url", "uploaderId") VALUES (NULL, ?, 2) -- PARAMETERS: ["youtube.com/derp"]

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

  console.log
    query failed: INSERT INTO "upload_info"("id", "url", "uploaderId") VALUES (NULL, ?, 2) -- PARAMETERS: ["youtube.com/derp"]

      at Function.logError (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:233:17)

  console.log
    error: [Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed] {
      errno: 19,
      code: 'SQLITE_CONSTRAINT'
    }

      at Function.logError (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:233:17)

  console.log
    query: ROLLBACK

      at Function.logInfo (src/platform/PlatformTools.ts:229:17)

 FAIL  dist/tests/YoutubeAccount.test.js (5.565 s)
  × Insert into database (393 ms)
  ○ skipped Upload a video
  ○ skipped Signs in to an account
  ○ skipped Registers an account

  ● Insert into database

    QueryFailedError: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

      at Statement.handler (src/driver/sqlite/SqliteQueryRunner.ts:113:26)
```